# ranking column in r without skipping ties

Tags: r, rank

I want to rank a column with ties, but not skip the next number if there are ties. currently when I do:

```
A         B
group1   325
group1   325
group1   123 

C <- df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(rank(-B, ties.method = "min")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

I get

```
A         B   C
group1   325  1
group1   325  1
group1   123  3
```

Is there a way to make it not skip the number 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dense_rank`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(A) %>%
   mutate(C = dense_rank(-B)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  A          B     C
  <chr>  <int> <int>
1 group1   325     1
2 group1   325     1
3 group1   123     2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = c("group1", "group1", "group1"), B = c(325L, 
325L, 123L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```